# How to remove the 'Optional' text from WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjvOA.png)

Hi I have tried to remove the optional text from these fields but have ran out of luck. Does anyone know a code that can help remove the word optional? Thank you

I tried this below but did not work

```
`add_filter( ‘woocommerce_form_field’ , ‘elex_remove_checkout_optional_text’, 10, 4 );
function elex_remove_checkout_optional_text( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
$optional = ‘ (‘ . esc_html__( ‘optional’, ‘woocommerce’ ) . ‘)‘;
$field = str_replace( $optional, ”, $field );
return $field;
}`
```